# Failed to create CoreCLR, HRESULT: 0x80004005

Tags: asp.net

I had clone a microservices in my local device and when ever I started that project I got that error
IIS Express is running.
Failed to create CoreCLR, HRESULT: 0x80004005

HTTP Error 500.30 - ASP.NET Core app failed to start
Common solutions to this issue:
The app failed to start
The app started but then stopped
The app started but threw an exception during startup
Troubleshooting steps:
Check the system event log for error messages
Enable logging the application process' stdout messages
Attach a debugger to the application process and inspect

And this error come up in the view try each and everything like check environments variable check and updating Asp.net SDK's

And this error come up in the view try each and everything like check environments variable check and updating Asp.net SDK's

Comment: I have the same problem. One possibility it is coming is when the filesystem is read-only. It should be fixed as per https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/9336 but seems it's not.

Comment: Try to the environment variable `COMPlus_EnableDiagnostics` to `0` and run the app.

Comment: I also get this error when I try publishing my .net6 project through GitLab runner. to fix this issue I temporarily publish on my pc then deploy on server. really I couldn't find right reason yet for this issue and I also post this question.
In next step I want to reinstall .NET runtime on my GitLab server.

Comment: I posted this  question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76535634/net-application-aborts-at-startup-with-failed-to-create-coreclr-hresult-0x80

Answer (score 9):

@alvarez response was the solution for me (running asp.net 7 in k8s).

Set the environment variable `COMPlus_EnableDiagnostics` to `0` in either your Dockerfile or k8s config yaml, and it'll start & run correctly with a readonly filesystem!

Comment: We use Nix to build up testing environments, and the read-only file system was defeating my .NET-on-Linux efforts. I don't know if I'd have been able to figure this one out without this tip.

Comment: Works for my GitHub actions setup for Linux run.sh . Thanks!